# Is this comics in Riverdale S01E13 actually the comics that inspired the show?

Tags: comic-adaptation, riverdale

In my previous [Riverdale question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/106340/how-much-is-riverdale-based-on-archie-comics), I asked about the connection between the Riverdale world and Archie comics.

I noticed now, that in S01E13 when FP

> is arrested, he has some comics in prison:

---

> [image: FP in prison with comics 1]
>  
>  [image: FP in prison with comics 2]

**Is this the Archie comics?

In other words, is this an Easter egg that the comics in the show is actually the one that the show is based on?**

Comment: @Paulie_D I see you edited the picture size. Is there still an option to see it big? Before, it was possible to read some of the words on the comics that now aren't, which is crucial for the question. Should I revert it?

Comment: Reverted as requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He appears to be reading ["Chilling Adventures in Sorcery as Told by Sabrina #1"](https://www.comics.org/issue/25404/) from September 1972.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that is actually really interesting. According to the first link that Google got me https://archiecomics.fandom.com/wiki/Chilling_Adventures_In_Sorcery_As_Told_By_Sabrina_Vol_1 is published by Archie Comics. Also, there is another tv show [Chilling Adventures of Sabrina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilling_Adventures_of_Sabrina_(TV_series)) which is based on this comics. AND these shows have multiple crossovers with each other.

Comment: @TGar *Chilling Adventures **Of Sabrina*** is based on the recent comic series of that name (which is part of a "horror version" of the Archie comics) (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilling_Adventures_of_Sabrina ); the issue used in the episode is an issue from 1972 from the comic series  *Chilling Adventures **In Sorcery***.